# Spring boot docker container can not connect consul

Tags: docker, spring-boot, consul

I am new to consul. I have developed a spring boot application which can register itself and I can discover it from other application from console.
But if I try to containerize this application, it fails to connect to console: 
*I run console in docker containe*r:

```
docker run -p 8500:8500 consul:latest
```

Console starts and I can see the webpage:
http://localhost:8500

Then I create a docker image of my app and run that by

```
docker build . -t app
docker run -p 8888:8888 app
```

It fails to connect to console, and I get following error,

```
main] o.s.c.c.c.ConsulPropertySourceLocator    : Fail fast is set and there was an error reading configuration from consul.
```

I have following in **bootstrap.yml**,

```
 spring:
      application:
        name: app
      cloud:
        consul:
          host: localhost
          port: 8500
          discovery:
            preferIpAddress: true
            healthCheckPath: /health
            healthCheckInterval: 15s
            instanceId: ${spring.application.name}:${random.value}
```

Answer (score 2):

Got into a similar issue, the problem here could be with containers.
I solved it by making sure that the containers run under the same network.
Also, make sure to use container name instead of "localhost" in the above configuration.
Eg:

spring:

```
cloud:

  consul:

    host: consul //container name

    port: 8500
```